# Get unique values from nvarchar datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, nvarchar

I have a table in the SQL server database and it has a field with the type `nvarchar`. It stores the values in the  format as shown below:

```
   ROW 1 - ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
   ROW 2 - ["value4","value5"]
   ROW 3 - ["value2", "value1"]
   ROW 4 - ["value3", "value6", "value7"]
```

I need to get select all the unique values from here. So I need to get the following values in the result.

```
Result
------
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6
value7
```

I tried with the DISTINCT query, but it is failing. I am very new to SQL server and it would be very much helpful if someone can help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are valid JSON arrays so you should be able to use OPENJSON to extract the values:

```
SELECT value
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MyCol);
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyCol NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @MyTable (MyCol)
VALUES(N'["value1", "value2", "value3"]'),
      (N'["value4","value5"]'),
      (N'["value2", "value1"]'),
      (N'["value3", "value6", "value7"]');

SELECT value
FROM @MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MyCol);
```